# Dictionary comprehension with list.extend applied to each value

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I want to replace the following for loop into a one-liner dict comprehension

```
my_dict={'i':([3,4,5,6]), 'j':[10,20,30,40]}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    zeros=[0]*2  
    zeros.extend(value)
    my_dict[key] = zeros
```

into:

```
{key:([0]*2).extend(value) for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

However that does not seem to work. I have also tried:

```
{key:value.insert(0, [0,0]) for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

without success.

Desired output is

```
{'i': [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'j': [0, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40]}
```

Comment: Do you actually need new dict / list objects or why don't you just insert zeros into the existing ones?

Comment: `.insert()` and `.extend()` are method calls, which are *expressions* which evaluate to `None`, since they are *mutator methods*. You shouldn't use comprehensions for *side effects* though

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you "_want to replace the following for loop into a one-liner dict comprehension_"?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні can you explain why you want to know why I want to replace?

Comment: Because convoluted comprehensions are harmfully unreadable. Use readable code. That being said, you probably just need `{key: [0, 0] + value for key, value in ...}`.`

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні thank you for the answer. That actually works. We can have a long cup of coffee over stylistic choices. Fortunately this is for a solo project and I am a big fan of comprehensions.

Comment: Did you overlook my question or are you just not interested in the better alternative?

Comment: @KellyBundy I did overlook it as I did not really understand your suggestion. Did you mean to do it manually ...? The real dictionary I am dealing with is much larger than the example I provided. Maybe you can provide an example with code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "manually", although that just gave me another idea :-). Neither is a dict comp, though, and the question explicitly asks for a dict comp, so they wouldn't fit as an answer. My question is what do you really want, and perhaps widen the question so that my ideas *would* fit. Your original code keeps the original dict but replaces all the lists. Andras' dict comp replaces everything. My first idea wouldn't replace anything, would just insert zeros, and that might be the most efficient. (My new idea replaces everything, but might be efficient, too).

Answer (score 1):

`list.extend` and `list.insert` both return `None`. What you could do is just append the values list to a list of zero's:

```
{key: [0, 0] + value for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```